# Which algorithm(s) would be most appropriate for this?

Tags: algorithm, vmware

This relates to the location of VMs in VMware. Below are some important facts:

- There are multiple datastores, each of them of varying size
- Each datastore holds zero or more VMs of an arbitrary size, not exceeding the size of the datastore on which it sits
- The sum of all the VMs on a datastore will never exceed the total size of the datastore
- There is an 80% 'full' threshold applicable to each datastore, which is simply a capacity threshold we don't want to exceed

And now for the problem.

Sometimes we need to get rid of particular datastores for whatever reason. Our first approach is to attempt to relocate all the VMs on the given datastore to other datastores, but sometimes this isn't as simple as it would seem.

A simple example:

- 3x 1TB datastores
- DS1 has 1x 1TB VM
- DS2 has 2x 500GB VM
- DS3 has 2x 500GB VM

There is suddenly a need to delete DS1. Evacuating its VM directly to any other datastore would violate the threshold. The solution then would be to move one of the 500GB VMs, resulting in:

- DS1 has 1x 1TB VM
- DS2 has 3x 500GB VM
- DS3 has 1x 500GB VM

You then migrate the 1TB VM to DS3 in this case, to end up with:

- DS1 is empty
- DS2 has 3x 500GB VM
- DS3 has 1x 500GB VM and 1x 1TB VM

In doing this, you have evacuated DS1 without ever having breached your threshold.

This example is simple, but there is scope for more complex situations, for example where a VM has to be moved to a datastore then consequently moved back.

**I would like to know how I could program this logic.** I do not know much about algorithms but I am sure this can be done in a relatively straightforward way.

Comment: Ths is in essence the [bin packing problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem). It is known to be NP-hard in the general case, but there may be aspects of your problem that make one of the known algorithms feasible.

Comment: It looks like a variation of a knapsack problem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem . The difference is that you have more than one knapsack.

Comment: These are good, though I think my problem is different in so far as I have bins/knapsacks which are already packed.